# Como fazer uma função javascript executar corretamente com <option> e <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, html-select, option, html-option, selected-option

Já tentei de toda forma e não consigo que a função javascript **calcular3** execute corretamente. O resultado sai apenas com uma casa decimal e não obedece ao **option** selecionado. Detalhe: o código precisa ser em **javascript puro**.
Se alguém puder ajudar sou imensamente grato. 
Segue o código:

```js
function calcular3() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").value);
  var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").value);
  var t = parseFloat(document.getElementById("t").value);
  var z = x + y * t;
  var decimais = document.getElementById("decimais");
  if (decimais = 0) {
    var z = z.toFixed(0);
  } else {
    if (decimais = 1) {
      var z = z.toFixed(1);
    } else {
      if (decimais = 2) {
        var z = z.toFixed(2);
      } else {
        if (decimais = 3) {
          var z = z.toFixed(3);
        } else {
          if (decimais = 4) {
            var z = z.toFixed(4);
          } else {
            if (decimais = 5) {
              var z = z.toFixed(5);
            } else {
              if (decimais = 6) {
                var z = z.toFixed(6);
              } else {
                if (decimais = 7) {
                  var z = z.toFixed(7);
                } else {
                  if (decimais = 8) {
                    var z = z.toFixed(8);
                  } else {
                    if (decimais = 9) {
                      var z = z.toFixed(9);
                    } else {
                      if (decimais = 10) {
                        var z = z.toFixed(10);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>variável x</label>
  <input id="x" type="number" placeholder="x">
</p>
<p>
  <label>variável y</label>
  <input id="y" type="number" placeholder="y">
</p>
<p>
  <label>variável z</label>
  <input id="t" type="number" placeholder="t">
</p>
<p>Resultado: x + y*t = <span id="resultado"></span></p>

<select id="decimais" onchange="calcular3();return false;">
  <option value="0">0 decimal</option>
  <option value="1">1 decimal</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2 decimais</option>
  <option value="3">3 decimais</option>
  <option value="4">4 decimais</option>
  <option value="5">5 decimais</option>
  <option value="6">6 decimais</option>
  <option value="7">7 decimais</option>
  <option value="8">8 decimais</option>
  <option value="9">9 decimais</option>
  <option value="10">10 decimais</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numa comparação deve ser usado `==` e não `=`

- `=` - Atribuição, `a = 'b'`, atribui a variável a o valor b
- `==` - Comparação, `a == 'b'`, compara a variável a com o valor b

Seus `if else` estão péssimos*, em vez de fazer o que fez deveria fazer algo assim:

```
if (decimais = 0) {
    var z = z.toFixed(0);
} else if (decimais = 1) {
    var z = z.toFixed(1);
}
// ...
```

Ou seja, em vez de criar um `if` dentro do `else` deveria ser junto

Você também esqueceu de pegar o valor do select

- `document.getElementById("decimais")`; - Referência do elemento HTML
- `document.getElementById("decimais").value`; - valor do atributo `value` do elemento HTML

Outro detalhe, que não causa erro, mas não se faz assim:

```
var z = 'texto';
if(true) {
    var z = 'imagem';
}
```

`z` já foi declarado como variável não é necessário o uso da palavra-chave `var` novamente

Além de tudo isso, você está fazendo da forma mais difícil, simplesmente poderia passar o valor do `select` para o `toFixed()`

```js
function calcular3() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").value);
  var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").value);
  var t = parseFloat(document.getElementById("t").value);
  var z = x + y * t;
  var decimais = document.getElementById("decimais").value;
  z = z.toFixed(decimais);
  
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>variável x</label>
  <input id="x" type="number" placeholder="x">
</p>
<p>
  <label>variável y</label>
  <input id="y" type="number" placeholder="y">
</p>
<p>
  <label>variável z</label>
  <input id="t" type="number" placeholder="t">
</p>
<p>Resultado: x + y*t = <span id="resultado"></span></p>

<select id="decimais" onchange="calcular3();return false;">
  <option value="0">0 decimal</option>
  <option value="1">1 decimal</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2 decimais</option>
  <option value="3">3 decimais</option>
  <option value="4">4 decimais</option>
  <option value="5">5 decimais</option>
  <option value="6">6 decimais</option>
  <option value="7">7 decimais</option>
  <option value="8">8 decimais</option>
  <option value="9">9 decimais</option>
  <option value="10">10 decimais</option>
</select>
```

* Péssimos no sentido de:

- Ocupam mais espaço do que deveriam, do outro modo o código fica mais clean (limpo)
- Menos legível, a segunda forma fica mais clara a intenção

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua contribuição que, aliás, foi em tempo recorde! Entendi claramente sua explanação. Estou iniciando os estudos em javascript. A sua resposta resolveu o meu problema e foi uma aula sobre o assunto!!